# get just 1 number when scrolling, not several (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i use .scroll() i get every new position. That means that, with one mouse wheel movement, i get many numbers. I need to get just one number so i can increment by 1 each time mouse wheel is used. This is my code:

```
    let oldScroll = 999999;

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        let top = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log(top);
        if(oldScroll < top){
            //scroll down
        }else{
            //scroll up
        }
        oldScroll = top;
    })
```

Comment: use debounce or add in a simple timer which fires to update the value

Comment: Hello @LawrenceCherone, could you give me an example using the code above?